# SDL with g++: stdint.h: No such file or directiory

Tags: c++, g++, sdl, stdint

I'm trying to get SDL working using g++ on Windows 10, and I'm getting an error which states that stdint.h could not be found.

```
g++ -g -Wall -I includes/SDLm/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include main.cpp -o main

In file included from includes\SDLm\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2/SDL_main.h:25,
             from includes\SDLm\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2/SDL.h:32,
             from Window.h:1,
             from main.cpp:2:
includes\SDLm\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2/SDL_stdinc.h:71: stdint.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yep. This is an issue with MINGW, if you have MSVC > 9.0. The solution is to write the file yourself, as suggested [here](https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse/issues/5#issuecomment-361565752)

Comment: What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @CandyGumdrop egcs-2.91.57

Comment: @GregSalvesen Why on earth are you trying to use a 20-year-old compiler instead of a current one?

Comment: @GregSalvesen that version of the toolchain predates the adoption of the ISO standard C++ language.  Don't be surprised that it doesn't work in anything resembling an expected way.

Comment: @hvd @StephenM.Webb Oh, I didn't realize I was using such an old version. I updated to `gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0`, and I no longer got the error about stdint.h, however now I'm getting the error `g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`

Comment: @GregSalvesen If you're getting a `no such file or directory` error, I'd double-check your `include` lines in your headers an implementation files, as well as your main.